# How I can use JQuery Datepicker with a Icon and a Format in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to use jQuery for my Textbox. I want use the Datepicker with the format `yyyy-mm-dd` and with an Icon.

```
<script>
    $( "#txtVon" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true     
    });
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtVon" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You need to remember that unless you use Static Client ID's in your web config your txtVon box will have an ID similar to $contentSomething_txtVon, not just txtVon, so your JS won't run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using ASP.NET WebForms you are best to use **classes instead of IDs** when referring to elements, because the rendered ID will be different:

```
<script>

            $(".txtVon").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true
            });


</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVon" runat="server" class="txtVon"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: I would avoid the classes idea personally and stick to IDs. ASP .NET 4 has the client ID feature: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature or in all other ASP you can rely on the fact that the generated ID will always be the same. Inspect the textbox when it runs, then use that ID in your code.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough If you don't use .NET 4 `ClientID` feature, you cannot be certain the ID will always be the same. If a change is made to a name in the MasterPage, this will affect the ID of all controls in a WebForm.

Comment: @RyanMcDonough Classes are safe. These will never change. ASP.NET 4 static ClientIDs are basically a workaround because the IDs get re-rendered. If theres a way of doing something without having to use a workaround, I usually take that option :)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtVon.ClientID").datepicker({ showOn: 'button', buttonImageOnly: true, buttonImage: 'images/ui-icon-calendar.png' });
  });
</script>
```

Don't forget to include `js` file.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yyyy-mm-dd', new Date(2012, 1 - 1, 26));
```

I think that links [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#date-formats) and [here](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger) helps

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>

            $(".txtVon").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            buttonImageOnly: true,
            dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
            });


</script>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtVon" runat="server" class="txtVon"></asp:TextBox>
```

As suggested by [@Curt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13623602/370103) use class name to bind datepicker. Also, make sure that your image is exists in the mentioned path. The date format you can use for your desire result is `"yy-mm-dd"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the following files are available refereed.

```
jquery-1.5.1.min.js
jquery.ui.core.js
jquery.ui.widget.js
jquery.ui.datepicker.js
jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css
```

HTML code

```
<script>
$( "#txtVon" ).datepicker({
    showOn: "button",
    buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    dateFormat: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
</script>
Date: <asp:TextBox ID="txtVon" runat="server" CssClass="txtVon" />
```