# jQuery datepicker with standard ASP.NET Controls

Tags: jquery, asp.net

How do we make the date to appear in the textbox on the click of an image button using jquery and ASP.NET?

Comment: find the clientid of that server control and jQuery("#clientid").datepicker(); set properties you need of datepicker...

Comment: checkout [jqueryui](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: no research no try just posted here  so poor question .

Answer (score 4):

Here is a good example which may help you to use it.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/47474/ASP-NET-Control-from-jQuery-DatePicker-in-3-Minute

### Edit 1

You should check out the [jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/).

**ASP.NET Example**

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server" />
  </div>
</form>
```

### Edit 2

If you want to show button
Go through this linke
[How I can use JQuery Datepicker with a Icon and a Format in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13623539/how-i-can-use-jquery-datepicker-with-a-icon-and-a-format-in-asp-net)

Which suggest you to use like

```
$(".txtVon").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try like below code with class selector, know to more detail click on [jQuery Date Picker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtFromDate" CssClass="From-Date" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

           jQuery('.From-Date').datepicker({
                showOn: "button",
                buttonText: "Select Date",
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true
                }
            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#<%= txtDate.ClientID %>").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: generateURL("/Images/Calendar.jpg"),
        buttonImageOnly: true

    });

});
</script>

<asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```